# Issue with Forbidden Error when Accessing Django Backend through AWS API Gateway

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-api-gateway

My web application faces a perplexing 403 Forbidden Error when calling the Django backend (hosted on Railway.app) through AWS API Gateway (proxy). This error curiously only manifests in live scenarios, as testing the API Gateway endpoint from the AWS console works flawlessly. I've meticulously ruled out potential culprits like authorization mechanisms, Web ACL, and API key requirements. Interestingly, swapping out Django for a different backend, the Starwars API in this case, completely eliminates the error, hinting at a potential compatibility issue between AWS and Django in my specific configuration. To further isolate the source of the problem, I undertook the following actions:

- Deployed the Django app on both Railway.app and an EC2 instance, eliminating any platform-specific hosting issues.
- Configured Django to allow all origins and request headers, preemptively addressing potential CORS restrictions.
- Verified that no access-limiting resource policies were associated with either the API Gateway or the Django app.

These steps successfully ruled out both hosting and CORS as potential culprits, narrowing the investigation down to the intricate configuration of the API Gateway or the logic within the Django application itself.